# Is there a way to predict if a type is serializable as JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am working on a C# library which processes data given as user input. The shape of the data is arbitrary, I only expect it to be an `object`. It could be a simple record with two string properties, it could be a `List<T>` of such records, or anything else.

The only requirement that my library has in order to work correctly is that the given data can be serialized as JSON and deserialized again, without losing information. In other words, if I serialize to JSON and deserialize again, I want to be able to restore the original data identically.

Now, I can of course point this out in the documentation, but I would also like to support the users of my library programmatically, by presenting a warning to them if they hand over data that cannot be (de)serialized perfectly. The big question is just: How to detect this?

I originally thought of recursively checking that there are no non-public members, but this fails for records, since they apparently have some private members that are used by .NET itself. It's also not possible to use an exhaustive list, since users can come up with their own data types. I also cannot rely on specific attributes being set, and so on…

Is this even possible, in a reliable way, or should I just stop trying to do this, and put more emphasis in teaching people than trying to find a non-existent algorithm?

(Of course, I could just serialize and deserialize to test it, but I had hoped that there is a way to predict it.)

Comment: Simple answer: no, you can not.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having private members, as long as they don't hold state that is not therefore serializable. I don't see how you could predict this without the potential for hitting a halting state problem. For all you know, the consumer could have written a custom (de)serializer such that you don't know ahead of time if it will ever complete. You can check for cyclic references, but that's about it.

Comment: No, how would you decide whether as private member holds a state or not? It may even be the member holding the value for a public property. Even serializing and serializing may not be sufficient because there still may be some hidden state you cannot recreate with setting just public members.